# SQL query - CROSS APPLY OPENJSON - how to include PIVOT

Tags: sql, azure

I am new to the topic and would need your assistance. I am trying to resolve a JSON string via query and would need to pivot it now. What I am still missing is the integration of the PIVOT command.
Thanks in advance for your support!!!
Kind regards,
Michael

**Code:**

```
WITH request
as
(
SELECT requestId,
       property1191,
       '['+replace(replace(property1191, '[', ''), ']', '')+']' as json
from capex_management_requests
)
SELECT P.requestId, property1191, AttsData.[Id], AttsData.[data]
FROM request P CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (P.json, N'$') WITH (
    Id VARCHAR(200) N'$.metaId',
    data VARCHAR(200) N'$.data'
  ) AS AttsData
```

**Results:**

| requestID | Id | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 690 | 1 |
| 1 | 1192 | 4355 |
| 1 | 690 | 2 |
| 1 | 1192 | 4250 |
| 2 | 690 | 1 |
| 2 | 1192 | 4227 |
| 2 | 690 | 2 |
| 2 | 1192 | 4300 |

**Target:**

| requestID | 690 | 1192 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4355 |
| 1 | 2 | 4250 |
| 2 | 1 | 4227 |
| 2 | 2 | 4300 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the a PIVOT clause:

```
WITH request
as
(
    SELECT requestId,
           property1191,
           '['+replace(replace(property1191, '[', ''), ']', '')+']' as json
    from capex_management_requests
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT P.requestId, AttsData.[Id], AttsData.[data], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.requestId,AttsData.[Id] ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ) AS row_id
    FROM request P CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (P.json, N'$') 
    WITH 
    (
        Id VARCHAR(200) N'$.metaId',
        data VARCHAR(200) N'$.data'
     ) AS AttsData
) DS
PIVOT 
(
     MAX(data) FOR Id IN ([690], [1192])
) piv;
```

---

If you want to be dynamic, you need to materialized the result in a temporary table first:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataSource;

WITH request
as
(
SELECT requestId,
       property1191,
       '['+replace(replace(property1191, '[', ''), ']', '')+']' as json
from capex_management_requests
)
SELECT requestId, [690], [1192]
INTO #DataSource
FROM (
    SELECT P.requestId, property1191, AttsData.[Id], AttsData.[data]
    FROM request P CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (P.json, N'$') WITH (
        Id VARCHAR(200) N'$.metaId',
        data VARCHAR(200) N'$.data'
      ) AS AttsData
) src

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME([Id]) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Id])
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [Id]
    FROM #DataSource
   
) DS ([EVT]);

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'
SELECT *
FROM #DataSource
PIVOT
(
    MAX([data]) FOR [Id] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

Comment: Hi again, seems that the that "row_ID" and "690" will be mixed

Comment: requestID row_ID 690 1192
73718 4 1 3749
73718 7 2 4228
73718 6 3 3712
73718 5 4 3693
73718 2 51 3887
73718 3 51 4372
73718 1 89 4352

Comment: with latest code 690: 1 delivers 3749 but should be 690: 1 1192: 4352 => seems that pivoting mixes row_ID with 690 ID

Comment: [[{"metaId":690,"data":"1"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"4352"}],[{"metaId":690,"data":"2"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3887"}],[{"metaId":690,"data":"3"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"4372"}],[{"metaId":690,"data":"4"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3749"}],[{"metaId":690,"data":"51"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3693"}],[{"metaId":690,"data":"51"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3712"}],[{"metaId":690,"data":"89"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"4228"}]]

Comment: @MANTGX1983 could you post new question with your current query and the test data casing the issue. It's hard to copy/test from comments.

Comment: asked a new question right now - THX ahead for your support!